# Java (Swing): JScrollPane.setBounds() does not apply?

Tags: java, swing, size, jscrollpane, jlist

I'm trying to create a simple JList with a scrollbar, and therefore i need to have the JList within a JScrollPane. So far, so good. However, for some reason i can't resize/position the JScrollPane!? It sounds logic that everything inside it should stretch to 100%, so if i set the JScrollPane to be 300px wide, the elements inside will be as well. Is that correct?

While you're at it, please critisize and give me hints if i should change something or optimize it.

Anyhow, here's the code:

```
package train;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI {

    private DefaultListModel loggerContent = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList logger = new JList(loggerContent);

    GUI() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("title");


        this.addToLog("testing testing");
        this.addToLog("another test");


        // Create all elements
        logger = new JList(loggerContent);

        JScrollPane logWrapper = new JScrollPane(logger);
        logWrapper.setBounds(10, 10, 20, 50);


        // Add all elements
        mainFrame.add(logWrapper);


        // Show everything
        mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 500));
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addToLog(String inputString) {
        int size = logger.getModel().getSize();
        loggerContent.add(size, inputString);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance,
qwerty

EDIT: Here's a screenshot of it running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLGgQ.png

Comment: do you see the scrollPane on the screen with the list inside? or you see nothing?

Comment: Yes, i do see it on the screen. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/sLGgQ.png

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `setVisibleRowCount()` method of [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) is particularly convenient for this, as suggested in the relevant [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). [`ListDemo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ListDemoProject/src/components/ListDemo.java) is a good example.

Addendum:

> please critisize and give me hints…

Well, since you ask: Don't invoke public methods in the constructor; make them private or invoke them *after* the constructor finishes. There's no need to find the last index for `add()`, when `addElement()` is available.  Also, be sure to construct your GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) .

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422160 */
public class ListPanel extends JPanel {

    private DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    private JList list = new JList(model);

    ListPanel() {
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    }

    public void append(String inputString) {
        model.addElement(inputString);
    }

    private void init() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            this.append("String " + String.valueOf(i));
        }
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("GUI");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(list);
        mainFrame.add(jsp);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ListPanel().init();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. The only thing that don't make sense is the last main function, however, i haven't tread about event dispatching yet, and i'm really tired right now so i'm gonna do that tomorrow! Thanks for the hints, appreciate it!

Comment: @querty: For reference, the idiom in `main()` is discussed in [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). Also, don't be too annoyed with Andrew; I've learned a lot from him.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your JScrollPane inside a JPanel and add the panel to the frame.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add (logWrapper);
mainFrame.add(panel);
```

Then set the bounds of the panel instead of the JScrollpane

```
panel.setBounds(10, 10, 20, 50);
```

The probles is that Swing uses layout managers to control child bounds property. Adding a JScrollpane directly to the main frame, doesn't allow you to choose right bounds properly.

Comment: Oh, well this was unexpected! I tried your way, and it did resize/position itself. However, after trying to resize the JPanel, i got the same results as before! So i tried removing the setBounds() from panel, and only changed the values in logWrapper, and then it worked! So, it appears i need to have it inside of a JPanel, why is that?

Comment: @qwerty  Zen questions.  What are the layouts of the JPanel and it's parent container?  What is the default behavior of either of those layouts when a component is added with no constraints?

Comment: @qwerty: is that because you aren't using a layout manager. When you create a component the layout manager associated with it's father is responsible for laying the components. Frame hasn't a layout manager. If you put the JPanel inside another JPanel you will see that the setBounds called on the child panel will work how you would expect.

Comment: @Andres: All code i have is posted above. The default behavior is probably whatever the default action is, because i haven't changed it.
@0verbose: Thanks!

Comment: @qwerty: your welcome..i was having your same problems just few months ago.. If you think my answer is correct please mark it, and close this discussion.

Comment: @qwerty "All code i have is posted above."  How do you run the code with no `main(String[])` method?

Comment: @0verbose `JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);`  That is a terrible 'solution'.  If you do not understand how to use Java layouts, please refrain from offering advice.

Comment: @Andrew: I have a Main class, but it only contains the creation of an instance (of GUI) (i commented everything else out), so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : was just a suggestion to easy show him what was the problem. I had no time for a complete description of how layout manager system work

Comment: @0verbose  "I had no time for a complete description of how layout manager system work"  Fair enough.  Nobody here expects you to provide a 'complete & self-contained' answer.  OTOH I am *hoping* to convince you of the sense, in those cases, of linking to (for example) [Java Tutorial: Using Layouts](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).  Perhaps I reacted 'harshly' since I have seen far too many GUI abominations built around null layouts.  It gives Java GUIs, & Java GUI developers, a bad name.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : you are right. I had to be more precise, in order not to give wrong or incomplete answers to people that want to learn. You have surely more experience than me and i'll take in consideration your advices.

Answer (score 1):

The bounds & size of a component are generally ignored over that of it's preferred size and the constraints of the layout being used by the container.

To solve this problem, learn how to use layouts & apply them appropriately.

Comment: I believe i was using setPreferredSize() at first, but i had no luck with that either. And by the way, what does it look like i'm doing?

Comment: @qwerty "And by the way, what does it look like i'm doing?"  It *looks* like your wasting your time & my patience, at the moment.  Of course, that is just how it looks to me.

Comment: @qwerty: A complete example would be especially relevant if, for example, you had neglected the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) in your missing `main()` method.